# Windows Vista: image thumbnails do not appear or are suppressed

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer, images

I am having an annoying problem with image thumbnails in Windows Explorer:  they are no longer visible!  On occasion, when I switch to a new directory, I'll see some thumbnail images appear/flash briefly before being replaced with the stock icon for jpg/gifs...so it is as if there *are* some thumbnails, but for some reason, they are being suppressed.  Please note that I have no idea if *thumbnail generation* is actually occurring:  I don't see the little green progress bar in the Explorer location-name window when I change directories.

I have seen similar questions on this site and others, and I have attempted various solutions, all to no avail:

- Under **Folder Options**, The *Always Show Icon, Never Thumbnail* option is *unchecked*.
- Under **Performance** options (**Adjust Visual Effects**), *Show Thumbnails Instead of Icons* is *checked*.
- I have deleted the thumbnail database files via Disk Cleanup as well as manually (using Task Manager to kill Explorer first, then deleting the thumbnail databases before re-enabling Explorer).
- I ran a Microsoft "FixIt" tool which reset the *icon* databases as well.
- I checked the icon entries for the registered filetypes (jpegfile, etc.) in the registry for any abnormalities...everything *seems* fine, based on the various tips I used to check this.

Does *anyone* have any other solutions?  This is driving me *NUTS*!  Thanks!